# Simple input filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to do the following:

I have a long text, and i want to rip a part of him and add ..., that's not a problem, but i need to do this responsive, meaning:

If i have a width of 720px, i want this text to break after 30 char:

"Question 1: This is the greatest site ever to be red...",

Now when i reduce the width of the page i want the breaking point to be a bit early:

"Question 1: This is ...",

Should i achieve this using a filter, or filter is not the best strategy?

Comment: achieving this with css only would be better.

Comment: How exactly should i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

No need for filters here.